# react-loadable and server side rendering with webpack 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, react-router-v4

I am using `react-loadable` for `react-router-v4`and I want to do server side rendering.
Of course on server side I need not lazy loading, so I started to use `react-loadable`, because it says that it is possible to use with server with help of `import-inspector` babel plugin.

But unfortunately I got error in my server console `require.ensure is not a function`, which caused rerendering on my client side and I am losing all benefits of server-side rendering.

Before I had been using `react-router-v3` and used `getComponent` with `import` without any problem.

Here is my routes config.

```
export default [
    {
        component: Root,
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: Loadable({
                    loader: () => import('./Parent.jsx'),
                    loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>
                }),
                routes: [
                    {
                        path: '/',
                        exact: true,
                        component: Loadable({
                            loader: () => import('./Child.jsx'),
                            loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>
                        })
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

This is my `.babelrc`

```
{
    presets : [["es2015", {modules: false}], "react", "stage-2", "stage-3"],
    plugins: [ 
        "transform-runtime", 
        "syntax-async-functions", 
        "dynamic-import-webpack"
    ],
    env: {
        node: {
            plugins: [
                ["import-inspector", {
                  "serverSideRequirePath": true,
                  "webpackRequireWeakId": true,
                }],
                ["babel-plugin-webpack-alias", {
                    "config": "webpack/server.js",
                    "findConfig": true
                }]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

On client it works perfectly, only error is markup checksum diffing error.
How is this supposed to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to babel or babel loader

"dynamic-import-node",

That is from airbnb